# When I run a mixed model all my factors are not shown in the results

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have an experimental deign which requires a mixed model analyses. Just to give an idea, I have 2 groups control and exercise training intervention (Strength and Aerobics), pre e and post, after this first part control group was submitted to aerobic training, therefore data are independent and dependent. That's why I think a mixed model fits in this case.

This is my mixed model code, I got 2 factors, MOMENTO with two levels, pre (1) and post (5) and also GRUPO, which 3 levels,  1 (Combined training), 2 (Control)  and 3 (Aerobics).

```
 lmm_GML5_1 <- lmer(GML5_TER_BRUTO ~ MOMENTO * GRUPO + (1 | SUJEITO), data = Data)
```

Below I show you my results. As we can see, neither GROUP 1 or MOMENTO 1 are shown

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method 
['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: GML5_TER_BRUTO ~ MOMENTO * GRUPO + (1 | SUJEITO)
Data: Data

REML criterion at convergence: 694.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8062 -0.4838 -0.1120  0.4131  4.3846 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
SUJEITO  (Intercept) 25.78    5.077   
Residual             43.95    6.630   
Number of obs: 103, groups:  SUJEITO, 46

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      17.0000     1.9682 82.2119   8.637 3.72e-13 ***
MOMENTO5         -3.2481     2.2539 56.4144  -1.441    0.155    
GRUPO2           -0.8340     2.6352 85.6135  -0.316    0.752    
GRUPO3           -0.5776     3.0248 93.7429  -0.191    0.849    
MOMENTO5:GRUPO2   2.9126     3.0341 56.3067   0.960    0.341    
MOMENTO5:GRUPO3   0.2597     3.4966 56.6958   0.074    0.941    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                 (Intr) MOMENTO5 GRUPO2 GRUPO3 MOMENTO5:GRUPO2
MOMENTO5        -0.550                                       
GRUPO2          -0.747  0.411                                
GRUPO3          -0.651  0.358    0.577                       
MOMENTO5:GRUPO2  0.409 -0.743   -0.556 -0.264                
MOMENTO5:GRUPO3  0.355 -0.645   -0.269 -0.585  0.479
```

I also have not certainty of my next step after run the mixed model, I ran a ANOVA as I've seen in some tutorials however, but not so sure how I will infer that my group or moments are different from each other.

```
  anova(lmm_GML5_1,test="F")
  Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
           Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value Pr(>F)
  MOMENTO       116.107 116.107     1 56.555  2.6418 0.1096
  GRUPO          13.289   6.644     2 62.879  0.1512 0.8600
  MOMENTO:GRUPO  48.964  24.482     2 56.531  0.5570 0.5760
  >
```

Comment: Those are your reference levels described by the intercept. I think you mean also that MOMENTO1 is missing, not 5?

Comment: Yes, you are right!